# NodeJS | send email with korean charset

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to send a Korean email with `nodemailer`

This is the charset that exist in the raw mail:

`Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ks_c_5601-1987" Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`

What should I set for parameters `encoding` and `textEncoding` when sending from `nodemailer` via `sendMail`?

[Nodemailer configuration](https://nodemailer.com/message/)

When i keep `encoding` as `base64` the recipient get the email in gibbrish.